# Is there an function to simplify the following union type TUnitTransform?

Tags: typescript

Is there an function to simplify the type **TUnitTransform** as following:

```js
type TUnitTransform = ((...rest: [number]) => [number]) &
  ((...rest: [number, number]) => [number, number]) &
  ((...rest: [number, number, number]) => [number, number, number]) &
  ......
```

Because there are some common functions that need to accept transformed parameters (unit "px" to "rpx"):

```js
const fn1 = (rpx1: number) => { ... }
const fn2 = (rpx1: number, rpx2: number) => { ... }
const fn3 = (rpx1: number, rpx2: number, rpx3: number) => { ... }
......
```

And I have to transform them like that:

```js
const px2rpx: TUnitTransform = (...rest: number[]): any => rest.map((i) => i / k)

fn1(...px2rpx(20))
fn2(...px2rpx(20, 30))
fn3(...px2rpx(20, 30, 40))
......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From that information I'd be inclined to rephrase `TUnitTransform` as:

```
type TUnitTransform = 
  <T extends [number, ...number[]]>(...rest: [...T]) => { [K in keyof T]: number; }
```

The parameter list of this function is constrained to be of type `[number, ...number[]]`; that's a [tuple with a rest element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) and means that the list must start with a `number` and then contain zero or more `number`s after that. This has the effect of requiring at least one parameter.

The output type of the function is a [mapped array/tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) which has the same length as the parameter list, and whose output type is all `number`.  This transformation prevents the compiler from putting [numeric literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#numeric-literal-types) in the output.  If I were to just say `[...T]`, then a call to `px2rx(20, 30, 40)` would have the output of type `[20, 30, 40]`, whereas we want `[number, number, number]`.

---

And `px2rx` could be implemented like this:

```
const px2rpx: TUnitTransform = <T extends number[]>(...rest: T) =>
    rest.map(i => i / k) as { [K in keyof T]: number };
```

Note that TypeScript's [standard library's type signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4c62f6e7d62188d8fecb92300c72d1435924cb64/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1361) for [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) doesn't capture the preservation of array length, so I need the [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (with `as`) to avoid a compiler warning.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const n1 = px2rpx(20);
// const n1: [number]

const n5 = px2rpx(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
// const n5: [number, number, number, number, number]

// errors:

px2rpx(); // error!
// Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0

px2rpx(1, "two", 3); // error!
// -----> ~~~~~
// string is not assignable to number
```

That all looks correct to me.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1jAvDAjABjQbhgehzASRgBNwByWOMEAdwCg6oBPABwFMYAVAVTAEsonAE4BDSADMQQgLZIYAHk4w2ADyhswxCDADaYAK7SARmyEAaGADprB46Z0BdBwD4AFNctC20AFy6PnA4AlEjOMADeugDSMHxg8GxMIOJcDn62JkLYAL4MoJCwLCoATEJFfjz8gqISUrLIispqGlowGfYu7tZevlwhiM50MMMwPVCW0iIsrnyhsbjwISLakToxcQlJKYHphpkw2Zh54NAw4mAocq5lKii7dkL9YZG5+afnxVc3d217phY3Yr3TJPCIHOhvWDnADMXyKP3a5lGRSBvweAKK0OBplBLwY5xQXUsKJurmKaCCQToHyJJKKZLQFmhFKpMNpJVJ5KZjJgABYWccCm1Lsg6SoGUFsHQ8DBIcK-Ho-kIHILTmAAKxyMWuFAWYpMiy8izqyXS-ByjUKxEWa1ozI2pUOh4qs3KIRCKQQOjayW4fCmD1CACEroAoip2MB1MQYCJYAAbNjLWCXERCADmhg0UAgFiM+lg6ZAsDQDG1upgACIoDQQJWmb6ZQGpCGZQBaDsdsIAP17vdd0CEcXTsW01FgywgfHTYBERkTMCgIDtpgYDCAA)